# The method paintComponent(Graphics) doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I'm new to Java and I am trying to make a simple paint program where the user presses button to draw lines by mouse dragging

My problem is that lines aren't drawn on canvas although the properties of each line are saved.
When I try to draw line in the method of "mouse released" it works so I suppose that the problem is with "PaintComponent" but I can't find it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GUI extends JPanel{
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    private Point p1,p2;
    private List<pro> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
    private pro currentLine = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI window = new GUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public GUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        for (pro line : lineList) {
            line.draw(page);
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        if (currentLine != null) {
           currentLine.draw(page);
        }
    }

    private void initialize(){

        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 346, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas); 
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setLocation(10, 10);
        canvas.setSize(200, 241);
        canvas.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas); 

        JButton btnLine = new JButton("Line");
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLine);
        btnLine.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        btnLine.setForeground(Color.RED);
        btnLine.setFont(new Font("Stencil", Font.BOLD, 16));


        btnLine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            int x1;
            int y1;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        x1 = e.getX();
                        y1 = e.getY();
                        currentLine = null;
                    }
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        pro line = createLine(e,Color.red);
                        lineList.add(line);
                        currentLine = null;
                        canvas.repaint();
                    }
                });
                canvas.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                        currentLine = createLine(e, Color.white);
                        repaint();
                    }
                });           
            }
            private pro createLine(MouseEvent e, Color currentColor) {
                int x2 = e.getX();
                int y2 = e.getY();
                return new pro(x1, x2, y1, y2, currentColor);
            }

        });
        btnLine.setBounds(229, 95, 91, 31);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLine);

        }   

    class pro {

        private int x1, x2, y1, y2;
        private Color color;

        public pro(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2, Color color) {
            this.x1 = x1;
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.y1 = y1;
            this.y2 = y2;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics page) {
            page.setColor(color);
            page.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `Canvas`?

Comment: `JFrame`s are not meant to override`paintComponent`: they're multi-layered containers. If you wan't to paint a custom component, create a subclass of `JComponent` or `JPanel`, and then put it in (the content pane of) your `JFrame`.

Comment: I did that but still have the same problem @MauricePerry

Comment: Did you add your custom jpanel to your JFrame, you added a canvas instead?

Answer (score 1):

`JFrame`s are not meant to override `paintComponent`: they're multi-layered containers. If you want to paint a custom component, create a subclass of `JComponent` (or `JPanel`), and then put it in (the content pane of) your `JFrame`.

This works for me:

```
public class SketchPad extends JComponent {
    private final List<Line> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Line currentLine = null;
    private Color drawingColor = Color.RED;

    public SketchPad() {
        initialize();
    }

    public Color getDrawingColor() {
        return drawingColor;
    }

    public void setDrawingColor(Color newColor) {
        if (newColor == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Drawing color cannot be null");
        }
        this.drawingColor = newColor;
    }

    private void initialize() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            int x1;
            int y1;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                x1 = e.getX();
                y1 = e.getY();
                currentLine = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                Line line = createLine(e, drawingColor);
                lineList.add(line);
                currentLine = null;
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                currentLine = createLine(e, Color.BLACK);
                repaint();
            }

            private Line createLine(MouseEvent e, Color currentColor) {
                int x2 = e.getX();
                int y2 = e.getY();
                return new Line(x1, x2, y1, y2, currentColor);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Line line : lineList) {
            line.draw(g);
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        if (currentLine != null) {
           currentLine.draw(g);
        }
    }

    private static class Line {
        private final int x1;
        private final int x2;
        private final int y1;
        private final int y2;
        private final Color color;

        public Line(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2, Color color) {
            this.x1 = x1;
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.y1 = y1;
            this.y2 = y2;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics page) {
            page.setColor(color); //!! This first!
            page.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);  // **Then** this
        }
    }
}
```

Main frame:

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private SketchPad pad;

    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        pad = new SketchPad();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(pad, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }
}
```

UPDATE: a mouseMotionListener is needed:

```
private void initialize() {
    MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {
        int x1;
        int y1;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getY();
            currentLine = null;
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            Line line = createLine(e, drawingColor);
            lineList.add(line);
            currentLine = null;
            repaint();
            removeMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            currentLine = createLine(e, Color.BLACK);
            repaint();
        }

        private Line createLine(MouseEvent e, Color currentColor) {
            int x2 = e.getX();
            int y2 = e.getY();
            return new Line(x1, x2, y1, y2, currentColor);
        }
    };
    addMouseListener(adapter);
    addMouseMotionListener(adapter);
}
```

UPDATE 2: handle enable/disable

```
private final MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {
        int x1;
        int y1;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getY();
            currentLine = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            Line line = createLine(e, drawingColor);
            lineList.add(line);
            currentLine = null;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            currentLine = createLine(e, Color.BLACK);
            repaint();
        }

        private Line createLine(MouseEvent e, Color currentColor) {
            int x2 = e.getX();
            int y2 = e.getY();
            return new Line(x1, x2, y1, y2, currentColor);
        }
    };
```

...

```
private void initialize() {
    setEnabled(isEnabled());
}
```

...

```
@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
    if (enabled) {
        addMouseListener(adapter);
        addMouseMotionListener(adapter);
    } else {
        removeMouseListener(adapter);
        removeMouseMotionListener(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works, but I need to make the user able to do that only if he pressed the button and draw on specific space of the frame which can't be applied on the previous solution

Comment: @Sara_Youssef no big deal: see UPDATE 2